What is the relation of enterprise keywords with metadata navigation?
I'm reading about metadata navigation https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc?ui=en-us&rs=en-in&ad=in
After enabling the feature, the article talks about enterprise keywords.
What exactly is the relation between metadata navigation and enterprise keywords? I'm asking because the enterpris keywords don't show up in the metadata navigation tree.

In SharePoint Online, Enterprise Keywords and metadata navigation are closely related and are used to improve content management and the search experience.

please check the link:
https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/sharepoint-enterprise-keywords-the-ultimate-guide/

Business keywords are tags that you can assign to content throughout your SharePoint environment. These tags are not limited to a specific set of terms or group, giving you the flexibility to categorize content in the way that makes the most sense for your organization. By consistently tagging content with relevant keywords, you improve collaboration. Team members can quickly find and share resources, leading to more efficient workflows and better project outcomes.
On the other hand, metadata navigation in SharePoint allows users to filter and search content more efficiently in a list or library. By adding a business keyword column, users can enter one or more text values that will be shared with other users and applications for easy searching and filtering, as well as to enable metadata reuse and consistency.

What purpose does enterprise keywords serve in the context of that link and in general regarding metadata navigation?
